# Centering Buttons Without Filling

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm currently trying to get a start screen in a linear layout to have 3 buttons, each with equal space in between them and all centered on the screen. So far my setup is very basic with this format:

```
android:id="@+id/helpButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="@string/help" />
```

However, as soon as I add weight to the buttons the vertical portion stretches to fill the excess space instead of just centering the button as I expected it to. Even if I manually use dp, the vertical portion still stretches. Can someone explain the reasoning for this and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you want to arrange your button? vertically or horizontal?

Comment: @HamidGoodarzi I'd like them vertical. My linear layout has a vertical orientation also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i create the whole xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give this configuration a shot:

```
android:id="@+id/helpButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/help"
```